# Two custom injection annotations in Jersey 2

Tags: java, annotations, jersey, inject, hk2

How should I do the ValueFactoryProvider binding in order to have two custom injection annotations coexist in Jersey 2? Below I have included an example of my current approach and as you can see the Hello annotation injection "hides" the SmallTalk annotation injection.

Hello annotation:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.PARAMETER})
public @interface Hello {
}
```

SmallTalk annotation:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.PARAMETER})
public @interface SmallTalk {
}
```

Hello annotation resolver:

```
@Singleton
public class HelloResolver {
    public static class HelloInjectionResolver extends ParamInjectionResolver<Hello> {
        public HelloInjectionResolver() {
            super(HelloValueFactoryProvider.class);
        }
    }

    @Singleton
    public static class HelloValueFactoryProvider extends AbstractValueFactoryProvider {
        @Inject
        public HelloValueFactoryProvider(final MultivaluedParameterExtractorProvider extractorProvider,
                                         final ServiceLocator injector) {
            super(extractorProvider, injector, UNKNOWN);
        }

        @Override
        protected Factory<?> createValueFactory(final Parameter parameter) {
            final Class<?> classType = parameter.getRawType();

            if (classType == null || (!classType.equals(String.class))) return null;

            return new AbstractContainerRequestValueFactory<String>() {
                @Override
                public String provide() {
                    return "Hello!";
                }
            };
        }
    }

    public static class Binder extends AbstractBinder {
        @Override
        protected void configure() {
            bind(HelloValueFactoryProvider.class).to(ValueFactoryProvider.class).in(Singleton.class);
            bind(HelloInjectionResolver.class).to(
                    new TypeLiteral<InjectionResolver<Hello>>() {
                    }
            ).in(Singleton.class);
        }
    }
}
```

SmallTalk annotation resolver:

```
@Singleton
public class SmallTalkResolver {
    public static class SmallTalkInjectionResolver extends ParamInjectionResolver<SmallTalk> {
        public SmallTalkInjectionResolver() {
            super(SmallTalkValueFactoryProvider.class);
        }
    }

    @Singleton
    public static class SmallTalkValueFactoryProvider extends AbstractValueFactoryProvider {
        @Inject
        public SmallTalkValueFactoryProvider(final MultivaluedParameterExtractorProvider extractorProvider,
                                             final ServiceLocator injector) {
            super(extractorProvider, injector, UNKNOWN);
        }

        @Override
        protected Factory<?> createValueFactory(final Parameter parameter) {
            final Class<?> classType = parameter.getRawType();

            if (classType == null || (!classType.equals(String.class))) return null;

            return new AbstractContainerRequestValueFactory<String>() {
                @Override
                public String provide() {
                    return "Nice weather.";
                }
            };
        }
    }

    public static class Binder extends AbstractBinder {
        @Override
        protected void configure() {
            bind(SmallTalkValueFactoryProvider.class).to(ValueFactoryProvider.class).in(Singleton.class);
            bind(SmallTalkInjectionResolver.class).to(
                    new TypeLiteral<InjectionResolver<SmallTalk>>() {
                    }
            ).in(Singleton.class);
        }
    }
}
```

Resource configuration:

```
public class MyApplication extends ResourceConfig {
    public MyApplication() {
        register(new HelloResolver.Binder());
        register(new SmallTalkResolver.Binder());
        registerClasses(HelloResource.class);
    }
}
```

Resource using both injection annotations:

```
@Path("/")
public class HelloResource {
    @GET
    @Path("hello")
    @Produces("application/json")
    public String hello(@Hello final String hello, @SmallTalk final String smallTalk) {
        return hello + " " + smallTalk;
    }
}
```

Result when requesting the resource - should have been `"Hello! Nice weather."`:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found a solution! I added

```
if (parameter.getAnnotation(Hello.class) == null) return null;
```

and

```
if (parameter.getAnnotation(SmallTalk.class) == null) return null;
```

to the `createValueFactory` method of the two value factory providers.

Comment: This worked for me too, but it seems so inelegant. There has to be a better way. Have you found one, @Stine ?

Comment: One slightly better solution would be parameter.getSourceAnnotation() instanceof Hello. I know, not much better, but at least the method seems to be there for the very purpose of checking the annotation which triggered the injection.